# Finding smallest time interval (between now and date from array)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Currently working on finding the best solution to find the smallest time interval between the current time and a date inside of my array.

I have a method that takes a NSArray and returns an NSArray. The method does the following:

1. Loops through array sorted by time (`0` index is closest to current time)
2. Find smallest interval by finding the delta and comparing
3. Grab that index, fetch it, return a dictionary

I started to look in to using `timeIntervalSinceDate` and so on instead of the manual work I am using below.

The array looks something like this:

```
tideSummary: [{

'type' : 'High Tide',
'pretty' : 'January 16 at 5:13PM EST',
'epoch' : '325267782',

...

}]
```

---

Does this code seem to be bloated for what its trying to do? I feel there is a good chunk of duplication to extract certain data based on an index and a key value?

I want to return the closest time out of the array, so I wanted to use `timeIntervalSince1970` and do some simple math to find the smallest delta. My array contains a key that returns time in milliseconds

---

Any suggestions on how I can clean my conditional up so I can still extract: `lowTideTime` - `highTideTime` and `tideType`

**Below is my method I am using to extract this information:**

```
- (NSArray *)findUpcomingTides: (NSArray *)arrayOfTideCycles {
    NSTimeInterval currentDateInterval;
    currentDateInterval = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSInteger smallestDelta = currentDateInterval;
    NSArray *upcomingTideData = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < arrayOfTideCycles.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *eachTideSummary = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:i];
        NSInteger tideDateAsEPOCH = [[eachTideSummary valueForKeyPath:@"epoch"] intValue];
        NSInteger dateDelta = tideDateAsEPOCH - smallestDelta;
        if (dateDelta < smallestDelta) {
            smallestDelta = dateDelta;

            int iPlusOne = i+1;

            upcomingTide = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *tideTypeDictionary = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:i];
            tideType = [tideTypeDictionary objectForKey:@"type"];

            if([[upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Low Tide"] || [[upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"Max Ebb"]){

                NSString *lowTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
                lowTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:lowTidePrettyDateFormat];


                NSDictionary *upcomingHighTide = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:iPlusOne];
                NSString *highTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingHighTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
                highTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:highTidePrettyDateFormat];

            } else {

                NSString *highTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
                highTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:highTidePrettyDateFormat];

                NSDictionary *upcomingLowTide = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:iPlusOne];
                NSString *lowTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingLowTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
                lowTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:lowTidePrettyDateFormat];
            }

            upcomingTideData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lowTideTime, highTideTime, tideType, nil];
        }
    }

    return upcomingTideData;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can clean this up?

Comment: If your array is sorted, use a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question what you dislike is violation of DRY in this parallelism:

```
NSString *lowTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
lowTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:lowTidePrettyDateFormat];
NSDictionary *upcomingHighTide = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:iPlusOne];
NSString *highTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingHighTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
highTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:highTidePrettyDateFormat];
```

and

```
NSString *highTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
highTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:highTidePrettyDateFormat];
NSDictionary *upcomingLowTide = [arrayOfTideCycles objectAtIndex:iPlusOne];
NSString *lowTidePrettyDateFormat = [upcomingLowTide valueForKeyPath:@"pretty"];
lowTideTime = [self convertAndFormatDateToTimeWithString:lowTidePrettyDateFormat];
```

As far as I can tell at first glance, they are absolutely identical (aside from some unimportant local variable names). So factor them out into a method that takes the `upcomingTide` value and returns an array of the two tide times (or whatever it is that these two bits of code are supposed to produce for you).

Comment: Ok, thanks @matt. Yeah, basically if ```type == Low Tide``` -> store this, else use another.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

valueForKeyPath is a very general and complex method that will run relatively slow; objectForKey will be a lot quicker.

If your array contains data in milliseconds, then your code is in trouble. intValue only handles values between about +/- 2 billion. 2 billion milliseconds = 2 million seconds = a bit over a month. Use longLongValue or doubleValue. (If your data is actually in seconds, your code will go wrong some time around 2038).

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but this

```
    NSInteger dateDelta = tideDateAsEPOCH - smallestDelta;
    if (dateDelta < smallestDelta) {
        smallestDelta = dateDelta;
```

is wrong. Just step through it with the debugger and see how the values change. And I'm sure you'll want an absolute value taken somewhere in there.

Your code will crash if the last array element gives the smallest delta, because you will access the array element one further which is beyond the array.

If you have say 10,000 array elements, five thousand before and five thousand after the current date, you will find the best element so far five thousand times, and each time you do significant work. I'd first find the best array element, and when that is found, get the data that you want.

Comment: I am using that as a catch to find the smallest delta by comparing the current date/time in MS and the tide time in MS. I start with a high value for ```smallestDelta``` so it is get smaller on each pass. When the smallest catches I then grab the index.

Comment: Also updated my question with the array data to give an example if that helps.

Comment: When you say: ```I'd first find the best array element, and when that is found, get the data that you want.``` - thats what im trying to do is find the next tide time based on the current time. But you're saying its doing significant work on each index.